# Airflow (kubernetes executor) - Scheduling skipped because DAG record was locked

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

Need some help in understanding the locking behavior around DagRun scheduling.

We noticed that after a few DagRuns the subsequent runs are no longer getting scheduled and notice the following in the logs.

**{scheduler_job_runner.py:1426} INFO - DAG dag-test scheduling was
skipped, probably because the DAG record was locked.**

We are currently running a single scheduler pod. Would like to understand the locking behavior in general and under what scenarios does the lock get removed.

Currently the workaround is to restart the scheduler pod and the lock gets released but this isn't ideal for production. Would like to understand when does the lock get released for a DagRun in general ?

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Comment: Linking the related issue https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/36920 here. For us, restarting the scheduler pods didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: There's a related issue about it - https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/36920

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to clean all DagRuns. In UI go to Browse -> DAG Runs -> Select all dag runs -> Actions -> Delete/.